# with longValue Using equals to compare two reference

Tags: java

I was using the != to compare theses two fields, But I discovered I have to use the .equals to compare them.

```
    categoryId.longValue() != PDTO.STOREID
```

&& categoryId.longValue() != mDTO.getCategoryId()){

I edited my code like this, But It doesn't help me,(Cannot invoke equals(long) on the primitive type long)

```
    categoryId.longValue().equals(PDTO.STOREID && categoryId.longValue().equals(mDTO.getCategoryId()){
```

Any help?

Comment: What makes you think you need to use `.equals` to compare two longs?

Comment: You are missing a `)` after `PDTO.STOREID`. But are you sure you need equals?

Comment: What is the type of all your variables?

Comment: FindBugs is waring me this bugs with this :  This method compares two reference values using the == or != operator, where the correct way to compare instances of this type is generally with the equals() method. It is possible to create distinct instances that are equal but do not compare as == since they are different objects. Examples of classes which should generally not be compared by reference are java.lang.Integer, java.lang.Float, etc.

Comment: Type is Long in this case

Comment: Deciding whether to use "==" or "equals" method depends on what you want to do. If you really want to compare object references, then "==" is correct and you can ignore the warning. Otherwise, use "equals". So what do you want to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`equals` is a method, it should be invoked on an object - in your case, an instance of `java.lang.Long`. Just drop the `longValue()` and you should be OK:

```
categoryId.equals(PDTO.STOREID) && categoryId.equals(mDTO.getCategoryId())
```

Comment: is it ok to delete the longValue() here?

Comment: yup - you're comparing `java.lang.Long`s, not primitive `long`s.

Answer (score 1):

Primitives are compared with `==`. Objects are compared with `equals()` (otherwise you check that both variables point to the exact same object). So, either you use

```
a.longValue() == b.longValue()
```

or you use

```
a.equals(b);
```

Both are equivalent (except the first one will throw an exception id b is null).